# How to keep a normative Software Engineering when many .py files import duplicated packages?

Tags: python, code-formatting, python-packaging

I write some utility/ tool `.py` files, but it import many duplicated packages. And I will import these `.py` files in the rest `.py` files.

For example:

```
# tool_a.py
import a
from b import b_1
import c
from e import e_1
# some implementations in a.py.
... ...
... ...

# tool_b.py
import b
import c
from d import d_1
# some implementations in b.py
... ...
... ...

# tool_c.py
import c
import d
import e
# some implementations c.py
... ...
... ...

# And there are so many tools files like this
... ...
... ...
```

```
# Class A
import tool_a
import tool_b
# some implementations in Class A
... ...
... ...


# Class B
import tool_a
import tool_c
# some implementations in Class B
... ...
... ...

# And there are so many Class implementation files will include these tool files just like here
... ...
... ...
```

So if I just import these tools files one by one in each class file it will import so many duplicated packages and cause dependency problems

Sure it is a bad way, but I don't know how to solve the terrible packages dependency problems.

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about the multiple imports. If you tell python to import a module that is already imported, it will just access the cached module from when it was initially imported. The best practice is to just import the modules where you need them and not worry if the same module is imported in several files.